# MySQL natural sorting of alphanumeric values

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to sort alphabetic + alphanumeric values on following data:

```
In-Direct Labor
Level 1
Level 10
Level 11
Level 12
Level 13
Level 14
Level 15
Level 16
Level 17
Level 2
Level 3
Level 4
Level 5
Level 6
Level 7
Level 8
Level 9
Risers  Risers
Roof/Penthouse
Site
```

I have tried following solutions but it does not return result the way I want

http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/natural-sorting-in-mysql/

```
In-Direct Labor
Level 1
Level 2
Level 3
Level 4
Level 5
Level 6
Level 7
Level 8
Level 9
Level 10
Level 11
Level 12
Level 13
Level 14
Level 15
Level 16
Level 17
Risers  Risers
Roof/Penthouse
Site
```

Comment: The solution you linked only works in that very specific case. There may be something similar in your case, but only if your data obeys some rules. There is no way to implement natural sorting that works on any type of text data. So... Is the problem only relative to "Level" values?

Comment: Does it have to be done in `mysql`? This is easily accomplished with `php`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be extracting the first word and consider the second word as numeric in order clause:

```
select *
from ab
order by 
   substring(col,1, case when locate(' ',col) = 0 then 100 else locate(' ',col) end ),
   substring(col,case when locate(' ',col) = 0 then 100 else locate(' ',col) end ) + 0;

-- col contains your field.

+-----------------+
| col             |
+-----------------+
| In-Direct Labor |
| Level 1         |
| Level 2         |
| Level 3         |
| Level 4         |
| Level 5         |
| Level 6         |
| Level 7         |
| Level 8         |
| Level 9         |
| Level 10        |
| Level 11        |
| Level 12        |
| Level 13        |
| Level 14        |
| Level 15        |
| Level 16        |
| Level 17        |
| Risers  Risers  |
| Roof/Penthouse  |
| Site            |
+-----------------+
21 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer it works for all most of cases with period, comma and hyphen. I can see only issue with only digits and digits with hyphen not sorted properly

Comment: And need to change from 100 to 1 in SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * from Your_Table
ORDER BY substring(in_direct_column,6) + 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok... after having fooled around with [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40a69/10) a bit, I'll take a shot at this.

The following solution works well, under the following assumptions concerning the numeric part of the the text that you want to sort naturally:

1. **it must be at the end of the column**
2. **it must be preceded by at least one space**
3. **it must contain digits only** (no signs, periods or commas)

I have setup the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE phrases(phrase TEXT);
INSERT INTO phrases VALUES 
('In-Direct Labor'),
('Level 1'),
('Level 2'),
('Level 3'),
('Level 4'),
('Level 5'),
('Level 6'),
('Level 7'),
('Level 8'),
('Level 9'),
('Level 10'),
('Level 11'),
('Level 12'),
('Level 13'),
('Level 14'),
('Level 15'),
('Level 16'),
('Level 17'),
('Risers  Risers'),
('Roof/Penthouse'),
('Site'),
('Square 1'),
('Square 4'),
('Square 9'),
('Square 16'),
('Square 25'),
('Square 36'),
('Square 49'),
('Square 64'),
('Square 81'),
('Square 100'),
('Square 121');
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT phrase,
  (CASE
    WHEN phrase REGEXP '[0-9]+$' THEN LEFT(phrase,
      LENGTH(phrase)-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(phrase,' ',-1)))
    ELSE                              phrase
  END)                             AS phrase_base,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(phrase,' ',-1)+0 AS phrase_index
FROM phrases
ORDER BY phrase_base, phrase_index;
```

This returns the rows as desired (and as inserted).

### How this works

The REGEXP isolates the rows that end with a numerical string and pulls out all that precedes it and puts it in phrase_base. For other rows, the full text content is copied directly in phrase_base.

The numerical string at the end is converted into a number (phrase_index).

Sorting is done on the combination of phrase_base and phrase_index.

### Things to be aware of

On big data this will be slow, as indexes won't help much

This may not work well with multi-byte text columns, as the LENGTH function counts bytes, not characters. And I think that the REGEXP also does not work properly with multi-byte.

Comment: Why submit 50 queries when you can submit one?